# Which is the best os for a penetration tester in 2016 and why is the best?

Tags: penetration-test

I mean open source os and not.

Comment: Welcome to the security stack! "Opinion" based questions aren't in scope around here, so you're likely to have your question put on hold. Is there a way you can rephrase your question to ask something specific that doesn't invite opinion?

Comment: In addition, time-based questions aren't usually the way to go on Stack Exchange - as things change, you can add new answers to old questions.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure the OS matters.  It's the tester that matters.  Most of the precompiled OS builds for pen testing have lots of cool tools, but if you don't know how to use them, install them, and customize them then it doesn't really matter.

Most people I know in the business use a custom build of Kali running on a Macbook Pro.